# jquery .prop('defaultSelected') seems to malfunction in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

This is my code:

```
$selects = $('select');
$selects.val( $selects.prop('defaultSelected'));
```

It should resetting the values of all my select elements, but it does not work properly with just one of my elements in IE9. The only difference between them all is that this one i hard coded in a html-file, the rest is rendered with backbone (same structure though!).
Markup:

```
<label>
    <span class="heading">Heading</span>
    <select name="someStatus">
        <option value="Val1" selected="selected">Val2</option>
        <option value="Val2">Val2</option>
        <option value="Val3" >Val3</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

I imitated upper case and lower case, so if that could affect, you can take that in minds as well. :)

So, can anyone find what i am clearly missing?

Comment: `.defaultSelected` is (just as `.selected`) a property of each `<option>` element, not of the `<select>`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't actually do what you think it does.

It attempts to set as `.val()` the property `defaultSelected` of the first `select` only. Furthermore, there is no such property for `select`s. `defaultSelected` will be true only for `option`s (not `select`s) if they were the default selected `option`.

The following approach uses `.val()`, as your code ([demo jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/KxkLU/7/)):

```
$selects.val(function () {
    return $(this).find('option').filter(function () {
        return $(this).prop('defaultSelected');
    }).val();
});
```

If you'd rather use `.prop()` or if you have `<select multiple>`, you should use:

```
$selects.find('option').prop('selected', function () {
    return $(this).prop('defaultSelected');
});
```

See [**demo for this here**](http://jsfiddle.net/KxkLU/8/).

<sub>Note: Keep in mind `defaultSelected` **can** be changed programmatically, so make sure you know the boundaries of your code.</sub>

Comment: Your code doesn't work with `<select multiple>`s. See my answer for how to do it better (and easier)

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't, as it was not supposed to. I added a snippet for `< select multiple>`. As for better or simpler, it is a matter of opinion, yes?

Comment: Really nice to see people that actually can describe whats happening. I'm going to try some solutions today and keep you all updated. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't quite right. When you call `.val()`, it applies the *single* value you pass in to *all* the elements. You probably want:

```
$selects.val(function() { return $(this).prop('defaultSelected'); });
```

In your code, you fetched the "defaultSelected" property of the very first `<select>` element in the set.  That property value was being used to set *all* the `<select>` elements, so those without an option having that value would not be affected.  By passing a function, you're telling jQuery to ask what value to use for each one in the list.  The function above just fetches the "defaultSelected" property of each element in turn.

*edit* — also, as @Bergi points out in a comment, the "defaultSelected" property is on `<option>` elements, not `<select>` elements, so you'd have to find the right one:

```
$selects.val(function() {
  return $(this).find('option[selected]').val() || undefined;
});
```

Comment: Makes perfectly sense. I will look into this during the day and keep you all updated. :)

Comment: Thank you for contributing! I used the solution @acdcjunior wrote, combined with your solution: `return $(this).prop('defaultSelected') || '';`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

`.defaultSelected` is (just as `.selected`) a property of each [`<option>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement), not of the `<select>`! Your code would therefore have set the values to `undefined`.

What you want is

```
$selects.find("option").prop("selected", function() {
    return this.defaultSelected;
});
```

Comment: Did not choose your answer, however, this also worked nicely. Instead of using plain JS i used jQuery as in @acdcjunior wrote. I know that plain JS has better performance, but i like to keep the same structure everywhere (jQuery code inside a jQuery .each() for example). Thanks for contributing!